# Button in android ignore background drawable resources

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, android-button

So, I am developing an android application, and across all the layouts that I have created so far, I have buttons, not `AppCompatButton` or `Material Button` just plain simple button which has the following attributes set:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/logout"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:text="@string/log_out_button"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_buttons"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```

**rounded_buttons.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#FFF"/>
<corners
    android:radius="8dp"/>
</shape>
```

This throws a fidelity warning:
  Paint.letterspacing() not supported.

The weird part is this xml when referenced in layouts created earlier works as intended. 
I appreciate any help you could provide.

If it helps this started after I installed a third party plugin to import material icons:

[Material Icon Generator](https://github.com/konifar/android-material-design-icon-generator-plugin)

I have since disabled this plugin, invalidated caches and restarted the ide, somewhere on SO, it suggested to change the theme, tried that to no avail, so changed it back to the one I was using.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty embarrassing, All I had to do was change the theme in the preview from 
`Material Components` to `AppTheme`.

Pretty stupid to not have figured this out earlier. 
Also the [Material Icon generator](https://github.com/konifar/android-material-design-icon-generator-plugin) is pretty great and did not cause this issue.